# Ensure Camera preview size/aspect ratio matches resulting video

Tags: java, android, video, android-camera, mediarecorder

I'm using the MediaRecorder and Camera classes to preview and capture video. My problem is I'm not really sure how to go about ensuring that what the user sees while recording matches the resulting video. My first inclination is to iterate through the supported preview sizes of the Camera until I find the best one that also matches the aspect ratio of the video size I set to  MediaRecorder:

```
camProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_480P);
aspectRatio = (float)camProfile.videoFrameWidth / camProfile.videoFrameHeight;
```

...

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

Size bestSize = getBestSize(parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes(), aspectRatio);
parameters.setPreviewSize(bestSize.width, bestSize.height);
camera.setParameters(parameters);

LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams((int)(videoView.getHeight() * aspectRatio), videoView.getHeight());
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

videoView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

...

```
mRecorder.setVideoSize(camProfile.videoFrameWidth, camProfile.videoFrameHeight);
```

Is this the right way to go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it worked fine for me, and as I've received no critique, might as well throw in the `getBestSize` functionality as well:

```
private Size getBestSize(List<Size> supportedPreviewSizes, float aspectRatio) {
    int surfaceHeight = videoView.getHeight();

    Size bestSize = null;
    Size backupSize = null;
    for (Size size : supportedPreviewSizes) {
        float previewAspectRatio = size.width / (float)size.height;
        previewAspectRatio = Math.round(previewAspectRatio * 10) / 10f;
        if (previewAspectRatio == aspectRatio) { // Best size must match preferred aspect ratio
            if (bestSize == null || Math.abs(surfaceHeight - size.height) < Math.abs(surfaceHeight - bestSize.height))
                bestSize = size;
        }
        else if (bestSize == null) { // If none of supported sizes match preferred aspect ratio, backupSize will be used
            if (backupSize == null || Math.abs(surfaceHeight - size.height) < Math.abs(surfaceHeight - backupSize.height))
                backupSize = size;
        }
    }
    return bestSize != null ? bestSize : backupSize;
}
```